# Volume quadrature over sphere using rectangular grid data

Tags: numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I have periodic data in rectangular grid stored as a Numpy array. I want to integrate the data within a sphere of radius `r` and center `a`.

- Is there any scipy function I can use?
- If not, what is the most efficient way to do it?